# Why do these two virtually identical requirejs calls not produce the same output?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have some code like

```
require("a/b");
```

which works fine. However, when I change it to

```
require("a/" + "b");
```

I get the following error :

```
Error: Module name "a/b" has not been loaded yet for context: _
```

Why is that? And how can I use require in the second style (or, more realistically, like `require("a/" + parameter)`)?

Comment: Hm, really? I'm pretty sure this is not possible.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't be possible, though. A string should be a string.

Comment: In the real code are you using literal strings like that, or is there a variable involved? I suspect it's the latter, and the variable doesn't contain what you expect.

Comment: are you using this on node.js? and with a build or optimizer step? certain tools scan for `require()` calls in the source, and they probably expect whole strings.

Comment: @Barmar Its the latter obviously, hence the last line, but if the vars are all strings it should be fine.

Comment: Like I said, the parameter probably doesn't contain what you expect, which is why it's failing. If you want help, show the actual code so we can figure out why it's going wrong.

Comment: I have to agree with @Barmar. A string is a string. I see no semantic or logical reason why the plain examples you gave would be different in any way. It must be something else.

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean the parameter doesn't contain what I expect? It contains a string, I'm sure of it. I'm looking at it on the debugger. Moreover, I have been able to simplify the case to use string literals in essentially the same style as shown above (aka without any parameters) and I get the same issue.

Comment: Then I suspect @dandavis is correct, this is coming from a tool that's scanning the source code, not from the `require()` function itself.